# python:can't install pillow in windows

Tags: python, django, windows, python-imaging-library

i am trying to install Pillow on Windows but every time the error below faces me:

*Note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

> ERROR: Failed building wheel for Pillow
> Running setup.py clean for Pillow
> Failed to build Pillow
> ERROR: Could not build wheels for Pillow, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects*`

I Have tried to install different Python versions and update setup tools
and the below commands:

python -m pip install --upgrade Pillow

how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

For the second one, you need to upgrade your version of pip first:

`> $python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

`> $python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow`

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html#windows-installation

For Python 3.8 on Windows, you need pip 19.3 or newer to install the prebuilt Pillow on Windows. You say you have 19.0.3 at #4456 (comment). Otherwise it will try and build Pillow from source, which is usually difficult on Windows.

[Source:](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4530#issuecomment-609485805) I personally tried it when I had the same problem